# variable scope in Tcl inside the procedure

Tags: scope, tcl, proc

I have below dummy program,

```
proc main2 {} {          
    set mainVar 100

    proc subproc1 {} {
        puts $mainVar
    }
    subproc1
}

main2
```

it throws an error **can't read "mainVar": no such variable**. my question is if I declare a variable (i.e mainVar )in proc isn't that variable should be accessible everywhere inside that proc? why it can't accessible in another proc which is declared inside mainproc proc? please put some light on this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tcl's procedures do not nest; there is no shared scope at all. The main reason for declaring a procedure inside another one is if you are doing some kind of code generation in the outer procedure (whether of the name, the variable list or the body).

Now, you *can* simulate a read-only version like this (simplified version; a full-service variant is a lot more complex):

```
proc closure {name arguments body} {
    set vars [uplevel 1 {info locals}]
    set prologue {}
    foreach v $vars {
        upvar 1 $v var
        append prologue [list set $v $var] ";"
    }
    uplevel 1 [list proc $name $arguments $prologue$body]
}

proc main2 {} {
    set mainVar 100

    closure subproc1 {} {
        puts $mainVar
    }
    subproc1
}

main2
```

I'll leave making it work correctly with `global` and arrays (as well as all the other nuances of doing this job properly) as exercises for the reader.